# Why does a global variable captured in a $.get() callback closure always hold the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables

I'm having a bit of trouble capturing the value of a global variable in my `$.get()` callback:

#### Relevant markup

```
<div class="block" id="blog"></div>
<div class="block" id="music"></div>
<div class="block" id="video"></div>
```

#### Relevant code

```
$('div.block').each(function() {

 $this_id = $(this).attr('id');

 alert($this_id); // outputs: blog, music, video

 $.get('test.php', {id: $this_id}, function(data) {

  alert($this_id); // outputs: blog, blog, blog (WHY?)

  $('div#' + $this_id).html(data);

 });
});
```

I'm trying to get HTML content and insert it into each of the *block* divs, but *$this_id* doesn't get changed inside the call to `$.get()`. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define *$this_id* within the function scope, or it'll default to being a global variable. Simply change this:

```
$this_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

to this:

```
var $this_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

It's a good idea to get into the habit of explicitly declaring all of your variables anyway... Much easier to keep track of them that way.

Comment: hummm...that solves the problem, even I'm not quite understand the var usage yet. BIG THANKS

Comment: @BigBalaBoom: `var` declares a variable, telling the interpreter which scope it will be limited to. You *can* declare a variable just by using it somewhere, but (with a few exceptions) this'll result in it living in the global scope. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/Var