# Jquery each(): variable in callback always has last value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navList">
        <li class="navItem"><a href="http://www.jacobsmits.com/placeholderRX.html">Discover</a></li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="http://www.jacobsmits.com/placeholderRX/documentation.html">Documentation</a></li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="http://www.jacobsmits.com/placeholderRX/download.html">Download</a></li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="http://www.jacobsmits.com/placeholderRX/donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.navItem').each(function() {
            $link = $(this).children('a');
            $link.hover(
                function() {
                    $link.css('width', '224px');
                },
                function() {
                    $link.css('width', '192px');
                }
            )
        });            
    </script>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sth3Z/

It should be doing it for each link, instead it only changes the last link no matter which one is being hovered over.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978911/closure-inside-a-for-loop-callback-with-loop-variable-as-parameter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555464/javascript-closure-of-loop

Comment: @pst - That is not the issue here. Did you read Rob's answer or run his fiddle?

Comment: @pst - Clearly the OP intended the `$link` to be a local var. And clearly Rob answered correctly.

Comment: @lwburk Just for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956698/why-does-a-global-variable-captured-in-a-get-callback-closure-always-hold-th

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `var` before `$link`: http://jsfiddle.net/Sth3Z/1/

```
    $('.navItem').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this).children('a');   // `var` added
```

Currently, you're declaring a global variable, which will be overwritten at each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Doh! Thanks so much. My minds been blanking all day lol. Also probably has something to do with all the PHP I've been doing lately. Damn varying variable scopes!

Answer (score 4):

why not

```
$('.navItem > a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('width', '224px');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('width', '192px');
    }
);
```

?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sth3Z/2/

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way of writing what u are trying to do:

```
$(".navItem a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('width', '224px');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('width', '192px');
    }
);
```